MS Word - Displaybarcode field to picture distortion
When I copy Displaybarcode generated barcode and paste it as picture, the barcode is distorted. Here is an example, the bars above number 6 are visible different. The first picture is the field, the second the image.
Sample example

Is there any setting in MS Word to avoid this?

fyi this is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question.

Just wanted to save you from the complete story: doing automated emails from MS Access through MS Outlook using MS Word as editor. The barcode pictures are in emails and some scanners can not read them. Then I realized that the problem is the picture distortion.
